# Multiple Onclick images

Tags: javascript, html

SO I am trying to create a screen that will display about 50 toggle buttons to display in a building on a monitor.

I want to create a bunch of images to use as the toggle so they are easy to see. This is the effect I want.
http://www.w3schools.com/dhtml/tryit.asp?filename=trydhtml_intro
except picture I want several light bulbs to turn on and off as I want.

Right now this is the code I have.
I am able to click the images to change as I want, they just wont go back, any ideas?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01    
    Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Untitled Document</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImg(img, newimg) {
    img.src = newimg;
    }


    </script>
    <body>
    <img onclick="changeImg(this, 'staten_uw.jpg')" src="staten_moored.jpg">
    <img onclick="changeImg(this, 'block_uw.jpg')" src="block_moored.jpg">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just for your own knowledge, w3schools is bad. http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't go back because the code always changes it to the _uw images.  If you want them to toggle, the function needs to check what image is currently displayed.  Something like this:

```
function changeImg(img) {
    if ( img.src.indexOf("_uw") > 0 ) {
        img.src = img.src.replace("_uw","_moored");
    }
    else {
        img.src = img.src.replace("_moored","_uw");
    }
}
```

will work if you have 50x2 different images, named "img1_uw.jpg", "img1_moored.jpg", "img2_uw.jpg", "img2_moored.jpg", etc.

If you only have 2 images, but want 50 buttons that each toggle between them, it's easier:

```
function changeImg(img) {
    if ( img.src == "staten_uw.jpg" ) {
        img.src = "staten_moored.jpg";
    }
    else {
        img.src = "staten_uw.jpg";
    }
}
```

Other answers have shown this quite simply as well.

Either way, the HTML should change to something like this:

```
<img onclick="changeImg(this)" src="block_moored.jpg">
```

Comment: SO here is my question in regards to that, I am going to have 50 images that I want to toggle, how do I add what you have there to all 50?

Comment: One way would be to set up a naming convention with the images so they can be treated the same.  For example, set it up so img1_a.jpg toggles with img1_b.jpg, and img50_a.jpg toggles with img50_b.jpg.  Another way would be to pass both image names into a `changeImg()` method, and compare the names directly (w/o regexes).

Comment: Well part of that is that each one need to be toggled idependantly.

Comment: Yes, that should still work.  When one `onclick` is called, it will only change the image for that button, since it's only changing the `img` element that was passed into the function, and not the other 49.

Comment: Basically waht this is going to be used for is a status board here at my command center (coast guard) it gets updated by the watch stander and will be displayed on a screen. So the watch stander needs to be able to be able to toggle which unit is underway and not on the fly. that is why i need each one to toggle as I need it.

Comment: Rewind - important question - do you want 100 different images?  Or 50 different elements that toggle between the same two images?

Comment: I guess I dont understand what your saying then

Comment: Ok, lets say I have 50 boats. I want to have 50 "buttons" so thats 100 pictures. each button will have 2 pictures. one saying they are underway, other they are inport. Basically i want the watchstander to be able to click each one and it pop the button up or down (images that I will make) to display underway or not for any of the buttons

Comment: No each one is goign to be graphically different. Doing your way gives me a javascript error. Does the <img onclick="changeImg(this, 'staten_uw.jpg')" src="staten_moored.jpg">  need to be the same?

Comment: OK i tried this and I get a java erro that says "java error on page"

Comment: looking at the details closer it says object does not support this property or method.

Comment: awesome this worked great. Thank you very much for putting up with me on this.

Comment: No problem - sorry it took so many iterations, and thanks for your patience.  I'm going to go back and delete some of my comments that aren't necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (i in images) {
        images[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var newsrc = this.togglesrc;
            this.togglesrc = this.src;
            this.src = newsrc;
        });
    }
};
```

and then use

```
<img togglesrc="staten_uw.jpg" src="staten_moored.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use only one img tag:

```
<img onclick="changeImg(this)" src="staten_moored.jpg">
```

and check logic in your js:

```
function changeImg(img) {
  img.src = (img.src == 'staten_moored.jpg') ? 'block_moored.jpg' : 'staten_moored.jpg';
}
```

Comment: This is only changes the 2nd image to match the first